# ValueError: time data 'LEGACY SYSTEM' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, csv, python-2.6, valueerror

I see this is a popular question, so hopefully someone can help me out. I, however, am stumped. I have CSV file that contains a timestamp in the first column, such as

```
18:49:45
19:50:31
20:51:26
```

My code is below. I think I am using the proper formatting for 24-hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
  import csv
  import time

  with open('file.csv', 'rb')as csvfile:
      filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      for row in filereader:
          date = row[0]
          parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%H:%M:%S')
```

Error: ValueError: time data 'LEGACY SYSTEM' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Comment: is it possible that your csv file has header row?

Comment: @buran yes it does actually, so I need to skip over those?

Comment: yes, you need to skip the header row. or use csv.DictReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a header row. You can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to retrieve (and then discard) the first line from your `csv.reader` iterator:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
from io import StringIO

file = StringIO("""LEGACY SYSTEM
18:49:45
19:50:31
20:51:26""")

# replace file with open('file.csv', 'rb')
with file as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(filereader)
    for row in filereader:
        parsed = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%H:%M:%S')
        print(parsed)

# 1900-01-01 18:49:45
# 1900-01-01 19:50:31
# 1900-01-01 20:51:26
```

If you have multiple, say two, header rows, you can use a `for` loop to ignore them:

```
for _ in range(2):
    next(filereader)
```

Comment: This is basically what I dead. However, I have 2 header rows. Is there a way to use next for more than one row?